# Not able to iterate a tuple using for loop

Tags: python, loops, tuples, iteration, iterable

why I  am  not  able to  iterate  a tuple  which i have input     as  using for loop  prints  tuple  as whole

```
t=tuple(eval(x) for x in input("enter values").split())
for i in t:
    print(i)
```

Comment: How are you entering the numbers? `1 2 3` or `1, 2, 3` ??

Comment: do you get error or what ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: always show example datawhich you use  (show in question, not in comment) .

Comment: Can you provide expected input and corresponding output?

Comment: Obligatory for beginners: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tuple from the input directly and then iterate through the for loop as given below

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple

t = make_tuple(input("enter values"))
for i in t:
   print(i)
```